# What does this error mean on the checkout page? "div class alert, error, token invalid" (WP, WooCommerce, Braintree)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, braintree

UPDATE: This issue isnt just because of the coupon site. i think it happens in general, so it must be related to the form, which is Caldera Forms. Does anyone have any idea what that means within Caldera Forms?

One of my customer is getting this error message in the process of checking out if they go to a coupon site, then go to our page from the coupon site.

> {"success":false,"data":{"html":"Submission rejected, token invalid</div>"}}

You can see the issue by (it sometimes happens, sometimes not):

1. Go to: https://www.couponbirds.com/codes/sprinly.com
2. Click on Get Code, then click go to Sprinly.com
3. Click on Get Started. Type in 44095 for zipcode and test@test.com
4. You'll see the error from above on a blank page

We use Wordpress, WooCommerce & Braintree.

Does anyone know what this means & how to fix it? The coupon doesn't work (on purpose). It was a referral code that got scraped by this coupon site from the website so we had to delete the referral code.

Thanks!!

Comment: https://joshpress.net/wordpress-nonces-and-wordpress-caching/

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It was a caching issue